# nginx - proxy_pass - 504 gateway timeout after two minutes

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, proxypass

*This question has been asked many times before, but none of the answers helped in this case.*

The following occurs on the `/api` location.

By default, Nginx is sending the 504 gateway timeout after one minute. We increased this timeout with `proxy_connect_timeout`, `proxy_send_timeout`, `proxy_read_timeout`, `send_timeout` and `client_body_tiemout` to ten minutes. Unfortunately requests still time out after two minutes with the same gateway timeout error.

We also overwrote the connection header to avoid any issues with keep-alive, unfortunately, this didn't help either.

Is there any other setting that might be limiting it to two minutes?

```
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_redirect off;

        # Handle Web Socket connections
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

        # proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Connection "";

        proxy_connect_timeout       600;
        proxy_send_timeout          600;
        proxy_read_timeout          600;
        send_timeout                600;
        client_body_timeout         600;

        location /api {
            proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:5001;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very unfortunate cant find anything https://serverfault.com/questions/287102/nginx-proxy-read-timeout-vs-proxy-connect-timeout

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest verifying that the source of the timeout really is the Nginx server. I've increased the timeouts the Nginx configuration to 5 minutes and then it turned out that in HAProxy the timeout was set to 2 minutes.